# Continuously listen to tcp port via terminal

Tags: terminal, netcat

Is it possible to listen to a port continuously?

I listen for incoming tcp notifications with following command

```
sudo nc -l -p 999
```

But as soon as notification arrives I have to restart listen with same command. Is it possible to listen to port without having to restart command when notifications arrives until user decides to abort listen?

Comment: Exactly, so whenever a notification arrives it should be printed in terminal without the need to manually restart command.

Comment: Does this work: `while true; do nc -l -p 999; done`

Comment: I get a syntax error

sudo while true; do nc -l -p 999; done
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Comment: If you want to use it with `sudo`, you have to use `sudo sh -c 'while true; do nc -l -p 999; done'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved with a simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

#Make Sure Script Is Ran As Root
if [ $(id -u) != 0 ]; then
    echo; echo -e "\e[1;31mScript must be run as sudo. Please Type \"sudo\" To Run As Root \e[0m"; echo    
exit 1
fi

echo "Enter port to listen"
read portL

while true;
do
    nc -l -p $portL
done
exit 0
```

Thanks dreamlax for the tip!

Comment: I would avoid putting `sudo` in the loop like that ... unless it is configured not to prompt for a password, it may cause issues if nothing is received for 15 minutes (or whatever the sudo timeout is configured on your system) and `sudo` is run again.

Comment: Better to remove sudo from script then run script as sudo?

Ex: sudo tcpListen.sh

Comment: Yeah, that would be better I think!

Comment: I would emphasize: just run this as the root user and have it check if real UID is 0.  Alternatively, run it as a user with sudo configured as  NOPASSWD ALL.  Two choices. You won't get far automating things if there's a prompt to deal with. (Don't try what some recommend, trying to "answer" the password prompt, ugh)

Answer (score 41):

Sorta outdated question, but came up first on my Google search.

In order for netcat not to shutdown as soon as the first connection is received, you can add the `-k` option.

From the man:

> -k Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its current connection is completed. It is an error to use this option without the -l option.

Src: https://superuser.com/a/708133/410908

Comment: On Debian -k is present only in nc.openbsd